# Access denied for database in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm just beginning at Laravel and I have some issue with the database. I tried to make a php migrate and got the following error :

[image]

here is my database.php file :

```
[...]
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
[...]

'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
        'engine'    => null,
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', 3306),
    ],
```

and my .env :

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD='password'

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

I tried several things like replace `localhost` by `192.168.10.10` or `127.0.0.1` in my .env but I still have an error. I also tried to do : 
`mysqladmin -u homestead -p status Enter password: secret` but It doesn't work, they ask for a password and no matter what I put, they tell me `error: 'Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'`

Comment: Make sure that your DB credentials are correct, twice check that

Comment: DB_PASSWORD='password' remove `'` if it is only `password`

Comment: Do you actually have a database running on localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this variables

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE="dataBaseName"
DB_USERNAME="root"
DB_PASSWORD=
```

note: that username is default to root and password to empty 

then run : `php artisan migrate`

it should work

Comment: _note: that username is default to root and password to empty_ erm sorry but no it isn't, this varies depending whether you're using MAMP etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your port number is wrong.

try this,`DB_PORT=3306`

instead of this, `DB_PORT=33060`

Comment: It didn't try alone, I had to combine both your answer and the one I validated. I upvote yours because it was something I already tried and alone it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Your database name, username and password are wrong, edit them on .ENV file with your database credentials. And try again.
Try to clear your config first

```
php artisan config:clear.
```

Close all the terminal /cmd windows and then restart terminal/CMD and this should get rid of the error message. See if it works.